# How to solve React error message: "Element type is invalid error"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving the following error when trying to import my Sidebar.js component into my App.js file:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Sidebar`.

I do not understand what to fix, as I feel that I am exporting/importing correctly?

Here is the code in my Sidebar.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import VenueList from './VenueList';

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <VenueList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code in my App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Map from './component/Map';
import Sidebar from './component/Sidebar';
import SquareAPI from './API/';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      venues: [],
      markers: [],
      center: [],
      zoom: 12
    };
  }
  closeAllMarkers = () => {
    const markers = this.state.markers.map(marker => {
      marker.isOpen = false
      return marker;
    })
    this.setState({ markers: Object.assign(this.state.markers, markers) });
  };
  handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
    this.closeAllMarkers();
    marker.isOpen = true;
    this.setState({ markers: Object.assign(this.state.markers, marker) });
    const venue = this.state.venues.find(venue => venue.id === marker.id);

    SquareAPI.getVenueDetails(marker.id).then(res => {
      const newVenue = Object.assign(venue, res.response.venue);
      this.setState({ venues: Object.assign(this.state.venues, newVenue) });
      console.log(newVenue);
    });
  };
  //Set and retrieve FourSquare information
  componentDidMount() {
    SquareAPI.search({
      near: "Austin, TX 78729",
      query: "bar"
    }).then(results => {
      const { venues } = results.response;
      const { center } = results.response.geocode.feature.geometry;
      const markers = venues.map(venue => {
        return {
          lat: venue.location.lat,
          lng: venue.location.lng,
          isOpen: false,
          isVisible: true,
          id: venue.id
        };
      });
      this.setState({ venues, center, markers });
      console.log(results);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Map {...this.state}
          handleMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick} />
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Code for VenueList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

export default class VenueList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ol className="venueList">
        <ListItem />
      </ol>
    );
  }
}
```

Code for ListItem.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="listItem">
        Test
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the source for `VenueList` too please?

Comment: Sure thing, made updates to my post with that information!

Comment: I think you need to enclose li into div in ListItem component and ol in VenueList

Comment: Could you Pleiades try wrapping your <ol> tag with div? If it doesnt work, I would be better if you check your import paths. They might be wrong.

Comment: As the error says, you are importing something that isn't exported correctly. Is the VenueList file exactly what you posted and isn't missing the `default` keyword?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! I tried wrapping my <ol> tag in a <div> but that didn't change the error. Also, my VenueList.js is exactly as posted, so it has the export default keywords. I believe my VenueList file is the problem I just cannot figure out how.

Comment: is the VenueList file exactly as you posted or are you passing in some props?

Comment: It is exactly as I posted